# EF: How to map multiple FKs in one junction table?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

EF with code-first on 4.3.1
Here is a simple schema for a fantasy sports tool:

[image: Schema]

It's a classic many-to-many relationship with a twist. The Player table has a compound key of PlayerId+LeagueId so that gets carried over to the junction table. (Note: PlayerId is not unique in the table, a given league (say NFL) might use the same playerIds as a different league (NBA for example)

When I try to define the mapping like this I get EF errors:

```
this.HasMany(t => t.Players).WithMany(p => p.FantasyTeams).Map(mc => {
            mc.ToTable("FantasyTeam_2_Player");
            mc.MapLeftKey("PlayerId", "LeagueId");
            mc.MapRightKey("FantasyTeamId");
        });
```

Like this I get the cryptic error: *Invalid column name 'League_LeagueId'.*

If I switch Right and Left I get: *The specified association foreign key columns 'PlayerId' are invalid. The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns.*

EDIT: here are the entities

**FantasyTeam**

```
    public int FantasyTeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string TeamEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
```

**Player**

```
    public virtual League League { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public int LeagueId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FantasyTeam> FantasyTeams { get; set; }
```

Mappings

```
public Player_Mapping() {
        this.HasKey(t => new { t.PlayerId, t.LeagueId });
        this.ToTable("Player");
        this.Property(t => t.PlayerId).HasColumnName("PlayerId").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(t => t.LeagueId).HasColumnName("LeagueId").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(t => t.PlayerType).HasColumnName("PlayerType").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name").HasMaxLength(255);
        this.Property(t => t.Team).HasColumnName("Team").HasMaxLength(50);
        this.Property(t => t.Position).HasColumnName("Position").HasMaxLength(50);

    }


public FantasyTeam_Mapping() {
        this.HasKey(t => t.FantasyTeamId);
        this.ToTable("FantasyTeam");
        this.Property(t => t.FantasyTeamId).HasColumnName("FantasyTeamId").IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.Property(t => t.Active).HasColumnName("Active").IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate").IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.LastModified).HasColumnName("LastModified").IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.TeamEmail).HasColumnName("TeamEmail").IsRequired();
        this.Property(t => t.TeamName).HasColumnName("TeamName").IsRequired();
        this.HasMany(t => t.Players).WithMany(p => p.FantasyTeams).Map(mc => {
            mc.ToTable("FantasyTeam_2_Player");
            mc.MapLeftKey("PlayerId", "LeagueId");
            mc.MapRightKey("FantasyTeamId");
        });

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: why do you need a LeagueId as part of the key in Player if player can be only in one league ? By the way, you can't have composite key in a table referring to a non composite key in another...

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sure it does. An ERD shows the high-level database model visually. These details are easily lost in code-first, and can be especially problematic when blindly "relies on the magic" without understanding the model or having some sort of target envisioned. Now, it might not be a *correct* or *works-well-with* ERD, but to discount it is to throw out a useful tool. (Disclaimer: I believe in model-first.)

Comment: @user2246674 - Yes, you can/should create and examine one _after_ the mapping and db generation but here it seems a starting point..

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think it makes a good starting point. The ERD can be visually analyzed and, as in this case, questioned and/or redesigned. Then the mapping onto the chosen model can be explored. It may be the case that the EF (code-first) approach doesn't align or could take advantage of a different mapping - but this doesn't eliminate the usefulness of designing/exploring the model first. The initial/target and code-first models can also be compared for "agreement of correctness".

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - PlayerIds are not unique, they are only unique for a given League. So for example you might have NFL players with playerids 1, 2, 3, 4 and NBA players with playerids 1, 2, 3, 4 as well

Comment: @snappymcsnap why ? You have no control on PlayerId ? I don't understand. If you have a Name property in Player, than player must be unique, or that doesn't make sense...

Comment: @HenkHolterman Why wouldn't I? Besides the fact that it's a preference for many developers there are many other reasons why this could be the case. Your comment is judgmental and unhelpful

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - The PlayerIds are not generated by me. And name is not unique either. Look up 'Steven Jackson' there's one in the NFL, another in the NBA and until recently there was one in MBL as well. Within a given league though, PlayerId is guaranteed to be unique

Comment: @snappymcsnap The important thing is not that the name is unique, but that the Player entity represents only one "person". Why don't you use a surrogate key (PlayerId) and have another SourcePlayerId for example (the one you don't generate) ? You could have a unique constraint on SourcePlayerId / LeagueId without having to play with composite keys, which are more complicated to manage.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus so you're telling me that this simple relationship is impossible to represent with EF?

Comment: @snappymcsnap Nono. But I think you should show your entities to clarify (at least  Player and FantasyTeam)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - OK they're as expected but I added them to the initial post above so you can take a look, thanks

Comment: @snappymcsnap sorry to be boring, but could you also show the mappings ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus - ok, added...I tried defining the many-to-many mapping  in each FantasyTeam and Player (and both) and it's the same result

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just tested this (simplified), which doesn't throw any error :

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
    {       
        public DbSet<League> Leagues { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
        public DbSet<FantasyTeam> FantasyTeams { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<League>().HasKey(m => m.LeagueId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasKey(m => new { m.PlayerId, m.LeagueId })
                .HasRequired<League>(m => m.League);
            modelBuilder.Entity<FantasyTeam>().HasKey(m => m.FantasyTeamId)
                .Property(m => m.FantasyTeamId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            modelBuilder.Entity<FantasyTeam>().HasMany(t => t.Players).WithMany(p => p.FantasyTeams).Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.ToTable("FantasyTeam_2_Player");
                mc.MapLeftKey("FantasyTeamId");
                mc.MapRightKey("PlayerId", "LeagueId");
            });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I have too. It doesn't throw any error until you try to query it and then it blows up with the error 'Invalid column name 'League.Leauge_Id' (which (note the underscore) exists nowhere in my code). The other weird thing is that I can query Player fine...like this: dbContext.Players.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PlayerId == 123); works fine, but the same query against FantasyTeam blows up

Comment: Hmmm, you mean you have data in your db ? How did you populate it ? Can you show which query throws the exception, than, maybe ? (I tried to populate some data and retrieve them, seems fine here).